# Nativescript Android physical back button override?

Tags: events, button, nativescript

How can I override my android physical back button so I can make my own code on it's event. I'm using newest nativescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var applicationModule = require("application");
var AndroidApplication = applicationModule.android;    
var activity = AndroidApplication.startActivity || AndroidApplication.foregroundActivity || topmost().android.currentActivity || topmost().android.activity;
activity.onBackPressed = () => {
   //Your code here
};
```

Comment: Thanks, in some reason this arrow function is not working (ES6 not supported??) but I edited it to use normal function so thanks it works!

Comment: Found a bug.. it works one time but after second time it starts to run same code as first time no matter what the view is.

Comment: Hmmm, it does not happen to me. Can I take a look at your code?

Comment: Well I'm using navigation module to "go back" and where ever I want user to go. lt somehow remembers the first back click code which is to navigate. I'm using same code on screen buttons and it works fine. This starts to repeat the first code where I click back button. Then If I go to other view and press back again it runs the same first code from another view. I dont know how this is possible.

Comment: Made more testing, I have a code on multiple different views and there is Toast text in every of them but with unique number. After first back press run it starts to repeat same toast on every view when I press back.

Comment: Do you define the onBackPressed() differently for different views? If not, it will certainly navigate to the same page as you have defined in the first one. I suggest using the `topmost().goBack` instead of navigation module if you just simply want user to go back to previous page.

Comment: I have that same onBackPressed() on every page, only difference is
"// Your code here" where I have another function call and there I have a code that is also run by on screen button which runs it perfectly. I need this onBackPress to start different functions on different views.

Comment: I just edit the answer, `var activity = ...` Let's try this in your code.

Comment: Okay, I'm really noob... I finally got it by moving the actual activity.onBackPressed function inside something that run when I go back to view, in this case navigatedTo event. I gues you now know what was my issue...